# Are there any Reporting capabilities or a way to obtain status updates in Trello?

Tags: trello

I'm a new user in Trello and I was not able to find any reporting or charting creation options.  Is there was way to get status updates or a way to generate any reports/charts in Trello?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no built-in way to do reporting in Trello.

However, Trello has an [API](https://trello.com/docs/), and there have been several blog posts about how to create charts from Trello data (like [how to create a burndown chart](http://echobehind.wordpress.com/2012/06/28/create-your-own-burndown-chart-using-trello-api-and-google-apps-script/)).

You might also be interested in 3rd party services, like [ChartBreeze.com](http://www.chartbreeze.com) which will let you easily create charts from your Trello data.  (Full disclosure:  I am the ChartBreeze founder).